# Heroku Rails app throwing routing error for resource show action only in production

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, routes, scaffolding

I have a Rails 3.2 application hosted on Heroku, and after local development of a new blog resource it for some reason is running into issues when on my Heroku staging application by throwing an error that says

```
 Started GET "/blog_posts" for 24.16.156.31 at 2014-09-16 01:27:59 +0000
   Rendered blog_posts/index.html.haml within layouts/application (25.9ms)

 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show",  :controller=>"blog_posts", :id=>nil}):
 app/views/blog_posts/index.html.haml:89:in `_app_views_blog_posts_index_html_haml___3120682798112947929_70212833553560'
 app/controllers/blog_posts_controller.rb:10:in `index'
```

Yet when I run

```
heroku run rake routes
```

to display all available routes I can clearly see

```
                       blog_posts GET        /blog_posts(.:format)                                            blog_posts#index
                                  POST       /blog_posts(.:format)                                            blog_posts#create
                    new_blog_post GET        /blog_posts/new(.:format)                                        blog_posts#new
                   edit_blog_post GET        /blog_posts/:id/edit(.:format)                                   blog_posts#edit
                        blog_post GET        /blog_posts/:id(.:format)                                        blog_posts#show
                                  PUT        /blog_posts/:id(.:format)                                        blog_posts#update
                                  DELETE     /blog_posts/:id(.:format)                                        blog_posts#destroy
```

at the top of my routes.rb file I have

```
resources :blog_posts
```

The only thing I could think of was that when I inherited this project and went ahead to generate the scaffolding for a blog, it created the blog_post_controller of type

```
class BlogPostsController < InheritedResources::Base
```

instead of the normal

```
class BlogPostsController < ApplicationController
```

which has all the explicitly defined show, index, new, edit, etc, actions that you can alter.

So to cause the scaffolding to return to ApplicationController I added to application.rb this line

```
config.app_generators.scaffold_controller = :scaffold_controller
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

blog_posts_controller.rb show and index actions

```
def index
    @blog_posts = BlogPost.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @blog_posts }
    end
  end

  # GET /blog_posts/1
  # GET /blog_posts/1.json
  def show
    @blog_post = BlogPost.find(params[:id])
    hash = session.exists?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @blog_post }
    end
  end
```

Additionally, the URL being accessed is

```
http://app.herokuapp.com/blog_posts
```

which should be triggering the index action, not show.

When I attempt to hit blog_posts/1 where 1 is a valid blog_post id, I get

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Rendered blog_posts/show.html.haml within layouts/application (31.9ms) 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"blog_posts", :id=>nil}):
```

routes.rb

```
resources :blog_posts
```

Comment: Can you please post your `index` and your `show` views, because that is the place where the error occurs. Do you have more routes in your `routes.rb`? Can you show the other route definitions?

Comment: If the error originates in index and show why does it work perfectly locally but not in the production Heroku application?

Comment: The stacktrace tells that the problem occurs in `app/views/blog_posts/index.html.haml:89`. Since you did not post that file and the fact that line numbers in view sometimes lead into the wrong direction, this is hard to answer. Did you double check that a BlogPost with the id 1 exists in your production database? Did you load the record that you pass to your url helper or did you hard code that id?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it turns out I was accessing a hard coded blog id that didn't yet exist. Please write up a brief answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to build an url with a BlogPost that does not exist. Did you double check that a BlogPost with the id 1 exists in your production database? Did you load the record that you pass to your url helper or did you hard code that id?